# Change DataSource in XtraGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

i have two different Lists.

```
List<MyClass> list1 = new List<MyClass>();
List<OtherClass> list2 = new List<OtherClass>();
```

I bind one of them to a xtragrid form devexpress:

```
gridControl.DataSource = list1;
```

That works. Now i want to change the list but the columns doesn't change.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call [`gridView.PopulateColumns()`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_PopulateColumnstopic).